# How do I create a memory for a calculator with hashmap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, calculator, stringtokenizer

Okay so I am building a simple PostFix Calculator in Java and I was asked to create a couple functions for it, one that I am struggling with is the memory. I heard you could do it with a HashMap, and I did research on it, but I don't think I quite understand how to implement it into my program yet. The way the Program will work is the User will Start it and it will say its a postFix calculator and will be prompted for input like this:

```
java PostfixCalc
Integer Postfix calculator with memory
>
```

but then he has the option to assign a variable to his input, for example:

```
> a = 3 5 + 1 -
7
> bee = a 3 *
21
> a bee +
28
> bee 3 %
0
> a = 4
4 
> 57
57
> 2 c +
c not found
> mem
a: 4
bee: 21
> exit
```

Here's my code so far. Im figuring i should tokenize the input and put it in an array list first in order to get the variable name, unless theres a better way.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Program6
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Servando Hernandez");
        System.out.println("RPN command line calculator");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(">");
        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
             System.out.print("> ");
             String a = scan.nextLine(); 
             String b = "quit";
             String c = "mem";
             String d = "clear";
             if(a.equals(b))
             { 
                System.exit(0);
             }
             else
             {
                  System.out.println(compute(a));
             }
             System.out.print(">");
          } 
      }



      public static String compute(String input)
      {
          List<String> processedList = new ArrayList<String>();
          if (!input.isEmpty()) 
          {
              StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input);
              while (st.hasMoreTokens())
              {
                 processedList.add(st.nextToken());
              }
          } 
          else
          {
               return "Error";
          }
         Stack<String> tempList = new Stack<String>();

         Iterator<String> iter = processedList.iterator();

         while (iter.hasNext())
         {
            String temp = iter.next();
            if (temp.matches("[0-9]*"))
            {

                tempList.push(temp);
                }
                else if (temp.matches("[*-/+]")) 
                {

                    if (temp.equals("*")) 
                    {
                        int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int result = ls * rs;
                        tempList.push("" + result);
                    } 
                    else if (temp.equals("-")) 
                    {
                        int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int result = ls - rs;
                        tempList.push("" + result);
                    } 
                    else if (temp.equals("/")) 
                    {
                        int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int result = ls / rs;
                        tempList.push("" + result);
                    } 
                    else if (temp.equals("+")) 
                    {
                        int rs = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int ls = Integer.parseInt(tempList.pop());
                        int result = ls + rs;
                        tempList.push("" + result);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    return "Error";
                }
            }

         return tempList.pop();
        }
      }


     private static String HashMap(String q)
     {
         List<String> memory = new ArrayList<String>();
         if(!q.isEmpty())
         {
             StringTokenizer var = new StringTokenizer(q);
             while(q.hasMoreTokens())
             {
                  memory.add(q.nextToken());
             }
         }


           HashMap h = new HashMap();
     }

 }//end of class
```

Comment: The Map interface and HashMap implementation are already part of Java. Map<String,Integer> resultsMap = new HashMap<>(); Then when you determine <var> = <result> you say resultsMap.put(<var>,<result) when you need to find the value for <var> you use resultsMap.get(<var>) (returns null if it doesn't exist, see c above) and for the mem command use resultsMap.entrySet() to get list of <var> <result> pairs.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea of the hash map for memory is that you would insert key-value pairs where the key is the variable name (a String) and the value is the value of the variable (an Integer).

E.g., after evaluating `a = 3 5 + 1 -` you would add `("a", 7)` to your memory hash map. Then when you want to evaluate `bee = a 3 *` you can look up the value of `a` in the hashmap, which will be 7, and then do the calculation with that. After that calculation you would add `("bee", 21)` to your memory hash map.

And on like that.